# How to toggle 'visible' attribute of form without post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I need 2 server forms to coexist in one asp.net page. That's only possible setting one of them as `visible='false'`. Visibility must change with the click of some button, but I need that without page load, I mean, via Javascript or AJAX. Note that we are talking about 'visible' control attribute, not `'visibility'` or `'display'` style properties!

```
<form id="form_add" runat="server" visible="false">
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT :**

From [forums.asp.net post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1412978.aspx?What%20different%20are%20there%20between%20Visible%20false%20and%20display%20none%20) :

> I think the important difference lies in whether you need access to the items inside the panels, client-side.  Setting visible=false will cause the panel not to be rendered, so you can't get at any of the controls, once again, client-side.  Whereas if you set display none, then you will have access to the controls, as the panel is rendered.

So if you want to show and hide it from Client Side then set visible to true and hide it with css and then you can toggle its visibility using jquery or javascript when you set **visible** to **false**, form is not rendered on page so it is not accessible at client side:

```
<form id="form_add" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" visible="true" style="display:none;">
```

Note that i am setting **ClientIDMode** to **Static**, when asp.net renders server side controls, there is a real chance that it changes the id of controls, so we can set control id static so that the same id is generated when rendered on Client Side.

[**MSDN Details**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

another [**LINK**](http://www.codeease.com/clientid-of-control-in-asp-net-4-0.html) for explanation of [**ClientIDMode**](http://www.codeease.com/clientid-of-control-in-asp-net-4-0.html)

and now you can toggle it from client side:

```
$("#form_add").show(); //  show it

$("#form_add").hide(); // hide it
```

Comment: Might be worth adding an explanation of the function of ClientIDMode here.

Comment: @Blexen added that as well

Answer (score 2):

I think the important question to ask first is: **where** are you adding that *other* form? In `ASP.Net Web Forms`, "there can only be one", and you *can't nest forms* ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)).

Then

- What is the "other" form's purpose?
- Must it be a server-side `form`? Or a `form` altogether?

  - must it send data (some/else)where?
  - that can't be handled by [`Button.PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you're not using a `MasterPage`, then you could add another/more HTML Form(s) outside of the server-side `form`. It will act as such, so you can't add server controls in it (but can still access `<input />` fields the bare-metal way).

Other than that, you can "inject" `forms` via Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

With JavaScript you can try using the `getAttribute('visible')` to check whether it is `true` or `false`.

And you can then use `setAttribute('visible',<boolean value>)` to set it to `true` or `false`.

You can call the `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` using `document.getElementById('form_add')`

Like:

```
Var t = document.getElementById('form_add');
if(t.getAttribute('visible')) 
    t.setAttribute('visible', false);
```

Comment: He's referring to the asp.net control attribute, which is processed server side, controlling whether the control gets rendered or not.